# managing multiple js projects in a yarn/lena monorepo

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, lerna, yarn-workspaces

I have a yarn workspaces monorepo that looks a bit like this:

```
root
   |_dependency1
   |_dependency2
   |_api
   |_graphql
   |_frontend
```

I am using yarn workspaces which is great but are there any tools about managing starting services etc.

For example at the moment, in order to start the frontend I have to:

```
build the dependencies
build api
start api
build graphql
start api
build frontend
start frontend
```

At the moment I start everything in separate tabs on my console.

It is quite unwieldy and could do with a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`npm-run-all`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all) package to orchestrate parallel/serial runs of npm/yarn commands.

[For instance,](https://github.com/mysticatea/npm-run-all/blob/52eaf86242ba408dedd015f53ca7ca368f25a026/docs/npm-run-all.md#run-a-mix-of-sequential-and-parallel-scripts)

```
npm-run-all build:deps --parallel build:api build:gql build:frontend --parallel start:*
```

(And of course you can "package" this up as a `scripts` script in your package.json.)